# How to detect which activity caused service to start in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

Suppose I have several activities called **A**,**B**,**C**.

From this activities I want to start a background service called **X**.

Is it possible to detect from the service what is the class name of the activity that started it?

For example, if the service has been started by activity **B** I should get something like **B** or **B.class**

I want to know if I can do this without hardcoding the class name by putting it as an extra in the intent that causes the service to start(so if i create more activities I don't have to add the class name in the intent for each activitity).

Comment: I guess you can Actions , so create constants for your activities and then in your intent 
check if the action equals the given constants for example

Comment: There is no way to get this information from Android. You will need to add the info to the `Intent` in some way yourself. Why do you need this information?

Answer (score 0):

First define a Context or an Activity in your class X.

```
public class X ()
{
    private Activity activity;

    public X (Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
     }
}
```

then create a method in your class X to get activity name

```
  public void GetName() {
    PackageManager packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();
    try {
        ActivityInfo info = packageManager.getActivityInfo(activity.getComponentName(), 0);
        Log.e("called from service", "Activity name:" + info.name);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

OR

```
 public void GetName() {
        String name  = activity.getClass().getSimpleName();
        Log.e("service",name);
    }
```

then you can call this method in your class B for example :

```
X service  = new X(B.this);
service.GetName();
```